# trying to upload Image in mvc web api project using jquery ajax only

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload Image but upon running my application my Image parameter is passing null, and I don't know why it is not picking up the file I attached

but in my browser console when I check my image file object that if it is attached or not, it shows that it does attach

[image]

but in my controller its passing null

[image]

my ajax code where I am passing the image file object,

```
$('.empOfficialDetails').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var data = new Object();
    data.UserName = $('#username').val();
    data.UPassword = $('#userpass').val();
    data.OfficialEmailAddress = $('#officialemail').val();
    data.Departments = $('#departments :selected').text();
    data.Designation = $('#designation :selected').text();
    data.RoleID = $('#role').val();
    data.Role = $('#role :selected').text();
    data.ReportToID = $('#reportToID').val();
    data.ReportTo = $('#reportTo :selected').text();
    data.JoiningDate = $('#joindate').val();
    data.IsAdmin = $('#isAdmin :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsActive = $('#isActive :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsPermanent = $('#isPermanent :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.DateofPermanancy = $('#permanantdate').val();
    data.HiredbyReference = $('#hiredbyRef :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.HiredbyReferenceName = $('#refePersonName').val();
    data.BasicSalary = $('#basicSalary').val();
    data.CurrentPicURL = $('.picture')[0].files; //this is my image file object
    //data.EmpID = $('.HiddenID').val();

    if (data.UserName && data.UPassword && data.OfficialEmailAddress && data.Departments && data.Designation && data.Role && data.IsAdmin && data.IsPermanent) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmpOfficialDetails',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var ID = parseInt(data);
                if (ID > 0) {
                    //var id = data;
                    $(".HiddenID").val(data);
                    //var id = $(".HiddenID").val();
                    $('#official').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#official').html("Employees Official details added successfully...!");
                    $('#official').fadeOut(25000);
                    $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();

                    $('.empOfficialDetails').html("Update &nbsp; <i class='fa fa-angle-right rotate-icon'></i>");
                }
                else {
                    $('#official').find("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger").remove("alert alert-success");
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert("There was an error while submitting employee data");
                alert('Error' + ex.responseXML);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseText);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseJSON);
                alert('Error' + ex.readyState);
                alert('Error' + ex.statusText);
            }
        });
        
    }
    return false;

});
```

but in controller on running the code it passes null

```
public void EmployeeImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".Jpg", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg" };
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName); //getting the extension(ex-.jpg)  

        byte[] bytes;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        }

        if (allowedExtensions.Contains(ext)) //check what type of extension  
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName); //getting file name without extension  
            string myfile = name + "_" + ext; //appending the name with id  
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/assets/img/profiles/employeeImages"), myfile); // store the file inside ~/project folder(Img) 


            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }

    public int Emp_OfficialDetails(Employee emp)
    {
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AmanraHRMS"].ConnectionString);
        var con = DB.getDatabaseConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_InsEmpOfficialDetails", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        #region Employee Official Details Insert Code block

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", emp.UserName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", emp.UPassword);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficialEmailAddress", emp.OfficialEmailAddress);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", emp.Departments);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", emp.Role);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAdmin", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsAdmin));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", emp.Designation);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportToID", emp.ReportToID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportTo", emp.ReportTo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JoiningDate", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.JoiningDate));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsPermanent", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsPermanent));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofPermanancy", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DateofPermanancy));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.IsActive));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HiredbyReference", Convert.ToBoolean(emp.HiredbyReference));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HiredbyReferenceName", emp.HiredbyReferenceName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BasicSalary", emp.BasicSalary);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentPicURL", emp.CurrentPicURL);

        #endregion
        var file = emp.CurrentPicURL;

        EmployeeImage(file);

        var ID = com.ExecuteScalar();
        com.Clone();
        return Convert.ToInt32(ID);
    }
```

and in my model class my Image datatype is as

```
public HttpPostedFileBase CurrentPicURL { get; set; }
```

I have no Idea what I am doing wrong If anyone who knows about this, your help is highly appreciated my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `JSON.stringify` to upload a file via AJAX. You need to use the `FormData` class.

[Sending files using a FormData object | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object)

```javascript
const data = new FormData();
data.append("UserName", $('#username').val());
data.append("UPassword", $('#userpass').val());
...
const file = $('.picture')[0].files[0];
data.append("CurrentPicURL", file, file.name);
...

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmpOfficialDetails',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        ...
```

**NB:** Unless you need to support Internet Explorer, you might want to use [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of AJAX. This can be much simpler, particularly when combined with [`async` and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: sir , I get your point but in your example you are passing the data in data parameter of ajax where to pass the const file parameter in ajax sir please I want you to clear my understanding of this

Comment: The file is appended to the `FormData` object.

Comment: Sir @richarddeeming I am not using the form tags In my HTML code I have written the input fields with out form tag in rows and column pattern, I have just used the bootstrap CSS class of input-group with all of my input fields and all input fields are closed in div tags  because of which the FormData() class is not working in my case, I want to know that if there is any other way for me to do this with out having the need to add the form tag in all of my code

Comment: The `FormData` class doesn't require a `<form>` element. What precisely does "not working" mean?

Comment: you are right I checked and form tag aren't needed, but as I run the code and open the inspect tool of my browser and start to debug traverse the ajax part of my code using breakpoints I saw that my FormData { } is empty only the file name has been passed thorugh ajax all the data in rest of the field was not passed through ajax

Comment: You've missed the `data.append` lines - you'll need one for each field you want to send. I included two examples in my answer (`data.append("UserName", $('#username').val());`); you just need to do the same for each of the other fields.